# How do I get a secure URL host for my Facebook app?

Tags: facebook, url

I decided today that I wanted to learn JavaScript and create my own Facebook game app.  I registered as a developer, but I do not have a secure URL host to manage my app.  I am coming from MATLAB and Swift, so I am new to this whole URL hosting thing.  When I typed in `google.com/` the app brought me to the Google homepage, and typing in `facebook.com/` and permutations of it doesn't work.  So, how can I get a secure hosting URL?  I apologize if this is very simple, but I don't know how to do it; thank you!

Comment: Secure hosting URLs need to use ssl, one option is google app engine has such a free service.

Comment: use localhost for development, no ssl certificate needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/) does work.  Thanks to everyone who commented!